# How can I move subsets of rows to new rows in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, analysis

I created a survey where respondents are asked questions about a number of other people. The resulting dataset has the following variables:
respondent ID  
Number of people you have information on (1-4) 
Person 1-Variable 1  
Person 1-Variable 2  
Person 2-Variable 1  
Person 2-Variable 2   
 etc...

If the person only had information on one person, all Person 2-3-4-variables are NA.

Do analyze this properly I need to restructure the data so that each line only has information on one person. So if a respondent gave information on two people, the variables for these two people should be on a new line. The result should be something like:

Respondent ID  
Variable 1  
Variable 2  
etc...

I tried a couple of things messing around with moving non-missing values around. But my knowledge of R is too limited to think of a proper solution.

Comment: It sounds like you need to pivot to long format. You can search for `tidyr::pivot_longer`, but we can't give you a concrete solution without a concrete example (a _description_ of your data isn't enough for us to go on, so perhaps using `dput` to get a reproducible example would help here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is to convert your data from a so-called "wide" format to a "long(er)" format. There is a handy function for this: `pivot_longer()` (see [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) for more details).

```r
library(tidyr)

X_wide <- data.frame(id = 1:3, P1 = 4:6, P2 = 7:9, P3 = 10:12)
X_long <- pivot_longer(X_wide, cols = P1:P3, names_to = "person", values_to = "score")
X_long <- as.data.frame(X_long)
```

This is the result:

```r
> X_wide
  id P1 P2 P3
1  1  4  7 10
2  2  5  8 11
3  3  6  9 12
> X_long
  id person score
1  1     P1     4
2  1     P2     7
3  1     P3    10
4  2     P1     5
5  2     P2     8
6  2     P3    11
7  3     P1     6
8  3     P2     9
9  3     P3    12
```

Comment: Excellent! This indeed works perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Mind validating the answer? (by clicking the check mark)

Comment: I tested it for the full data I just received and it might not be the correct way to do it. But maybe I posed my question wrong. The goal is not to reduce the number of columns, but to move them. The final dataset has 90 rows. The first 15 are identifiers, the others are 5x15 variables of person information. So this needs to be changed to the data having the 15 identifier-variables and one set of 15 person-variables on each row. So the amount of rows needs to go times 5. Is this also possible in pivot_longer? Because I have the feeling it might also need to done with something like unnest.